# How to parse russian WSDL xml into java object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, wsdl, wsdl2java

Using soap I have stored SOAP-Message which I got from W S D L link which is in Russian language in extensible markup language.

Now I want to parse this extensible markup language file to my java bean object. The problem is my bean which represent my database is in English text  and the extensible markup language files attributes names are in Russian language but their values are in English.

I know each of their respective name in Russian which are also their in extensible markup language file.

Please help me to parse this extensible markup language file into java object.

Comment: Can you please post one example of the WSDL link xml?

Comment: My link is in .wsdl format. Using SOAP i have successfully got the SOAP response and i have stored that message in XML format. Now the problem is i want to parse this XML file into java object and more bigger problem is that elements in XML file are in Russian language and variables of object are in English. Though i know which Russian word belongs to my variables. But still unable to parse it.

Comment: @krishna singh, could you add this xml to your question?